# curl (and openssl) two way authentication always fails

Tags: linux, command-line, curl, openssl, client-certificate

**Problem**
I'm trying to use curl to send a POST request to a web service deployed on tomcat with host and client verification is required (two way authentication) but I always get the response `404 Not Found`. The same result is achieved using openssl s_client. I have no clue of what I'm doing wrong.

**cURL Command I Used** The following are the commands I used and built from the man pages of curl as well as searching the internet.

```
curl 'https://hostURL:<port>/webservice/' -d '{"someRequest": {"name": "lol"}}' -v --cert webserver-cert.pem --key webserver-key.pem --cacert root-ca.pem
```

The output for the command above is:

```
*   Trying <ip>...
* Connected to <host> port <port> (#0)
* found 1 certificates in root-ca.pem
* found 872 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: <common-name> (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        <data>
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> POST /webservice/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: host:port
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 32
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 32 out of 32 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 1034
< Date: Tue, 19 Sep 2017 05:42:56 GMT
< 
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /webservice/</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/webservice/</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.14</h3></bo* Connection #0 to host host left intact
dy></html>
```

**openssl s_client Command I Used** The following is the openssl command I used built from reading its man pages and searching the internet:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port -cert webserver-cert.pem -key webserver-key.pem -CAfile root-ca.pem -msg -state
```

The following is the output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
>>> TLS 1.2  [length 0005]
    16 03 01 01 2c
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 012c], ClientHello
    <data>
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
<<< ??? [length 0005]
    16 03 03 0c 65
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0051], ServerHello
    <data>
SSL_connect:unknown state
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0ac3], Certificate
    <data>
depth=1 C = FR, ST = state, L = name, O = name, CN = name CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, ST = country, L = state, O = host, OU = Web server, CN = host
verify return:1
SSL_connect:unknown state
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 014d], ServerKeyExchange
    <data>
SSL_connect:unknown state
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0004], ServerHelloDone
    0e 00 00 00
SSL_connect:unknown state
>>> ??? [length 0005]
    16 03 03 00 46
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0046], ClientKeyExchange
    <data>
SSL_connect:unknown state
>>> ??? [length 0005]
    14 03 03 00 01
>>> TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]
    01
SSL_connect:unknown state
>>> ??? [length 0005]
    16 03 03 00 28
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
    14 00 00 0c 86 20 94 8c f1 d2 32 1d 95 10 40 7c
SSL_connect:unknown state
SSL_connect:unknown state
<<< ??? [length 0005]
    14 03 03 00 01
<<< TLS 1.2 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]
    01
<<< ??? [length 0005]
    16 03 03 00 28
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
    14 00 00 0c 04 c9 ef 15 6e cf 7f 28 2b 8f b3 4e
SSL_connect:unknown state
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=FR/ST=country/L=state/O=host/OU=Web server/CN=host
   i:/C=FR/ST=state/L=name/O=name/CN=name CA
 1 s:/C=FR/ST=state/L=name/O=name/CN=name CA
   i:/C=FR/ST=state/L=name/O=name/CN=name CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<data>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=<data>
issuer=<data>
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3229 bytes and written 431 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure RenFRotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN nFRotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: <data>
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: <data>
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1505765192
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Then I enter the post request as follows:

```
POST /webservice/ HTTP/1.1
Host: <host>:<port>
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 86
Content-Type: application/json

{request:{"username":"lol"}}
```

I get the same 404 error afterwards as well.

**More Details**

- I'm sure the path to the web service exists. In fact, I have client built in java that is successfully communicating with the web service. (this also means the tomcat is correctly configured)
- I'm sure the url and port as well as the ca certificate are correct. Used them to communicate with another web service that doesn't require client authentication and they worked just fine.
- The following are the curl and openssl versions.

curl

```
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
```

openssl

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

I'm going insane here as I have been going over the commands to make sure every single character I type is correct. Have been doing so multiple times. Searched the internet and learned that the commands I'm using are correct (at least, that's what I'm thinking so far).

Also, why am I getting `ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol` from curl and `SSL_connect:unknown state` from openssl?

Any help on the issue would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem and have been battling it for a couple years with some scripts I've been maintaining.  The problem appears to be that curl on Ubuntu 16.04 is linked to GnuTLS and not OpenSSL, and for whatever reason GnuTLS just won't send the client certificate in the request.

Comment: Did you ever solve this one? What would the curl-output look like with client authentication disabled?

Comment: @JariTurkia, yes. I found that the server was configured to work on a port different than the one I was using.